# Cholesky implementation in python - Solve Ax=b

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I'm using Cholesky decomposition for `Ax=b`  to find `x` , by doing `L*LT=A` then `y=L*b` and in the end `x=LT*b`.When I check though I don't seem to get the same results as doing the classic `Ax=b` . 
Here's my code :

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as sla

myL=np.linalg.cholesky(A)


#check_x = np.dot(A, b)
#check_x = np.dot(A,b)
check_x = sla.solve(A, b)

#check if the composition was done right
myLT=myL.T.conj() #transpose matrix
Ac=np.dot(myL,myLT) #should give the original matrix A



#y=np.dot(myL,b)
y = sla.solve_triangular(myL, b)

#x=np.dot(myL.T.conj(),y)
x = sla.solve_triangular(myLT, b)
```

Comment: Take a look at [this description in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Applications).  In particular, "solving L y = b  for y by forward substitution, and finally solving L ∗ x = y  for x by back substitution."  Your code is just multiplying, not solving.

Comment: you're right , I changed it but still getting wrong results , I'll edit my code with the update

Comment: maybe the problem is on the Forward and back substitution , that the first is used for  Ly=b and second for Lx=y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was sleepless and tired , I got the last line wrong it actually is

```
x=np.linalg.solve(myLT, y)
```

Comment: correct will be to use `cho_factor, cho_solve`, I explained in my answer

Answer (score 0):

> When I check though I don't seem to get the same results as doing the
> classic Ax=b

did you check in real example

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg as la
from scipy.linalg import cho_factor, cho_solve

A =  np.array([[1,3,5], [3,13,23], [5,23,42]])
b =   np.array([3,13,23])

check_x = la.solve(A, b)
print("check_x: ", check_x) # x:  [0. 1. 0.] <<<<<<<<<<<< CORRECT

################### CORRECT
c, low_bool = cho_factor(A, lower= False)    # Returns a matrix containing the Cholesky decomposition A = L L* or A = U* U of a Hermitian positive-definite matrix a.
print(np.allclose(np.triu(c).T @ np. triu(c) - A, np.zeros(3)))
x = cho_solve((c, low_bool), b)    # Solve the linear equations A x = b, given the Cholesky factorization of A. !
print("x: ", x)     # x:  [0. 1. 0.] <<<<<<<<<<<< CORRECT
print(np.allclose(A @ x - b, np.zeros(3)))

################### check your solution

L = la.cholesky(A, lower=True)    # Cholesky-factorization
##print("reconstruct A: \n", L@L.T.conj())

x1 = la.solve(L, b)     # your solution
print("solve ", x1)     # [3. 2. 0.] <<<<<<<<<<<<<

x2 = la.inv(L)@b
print("L^-1 @ b", x2)   # [3. 2. 0.] <<<<<<<<<<<<<
print("x1, x2 ", np.allclose(x1, x2))

################### or in such a way

x_sol = la.solve_triangular(L,  b, lower= True)
print(x_sol)        # [3. 2. 0.] <<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

USE `cho_factor, cho_solve` (that is correct with `L@L.T.conj()`), because [solve & solve_triangular](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.cho_solve.html)  gives only `L^-1 @ b`here, `[3. 2. 0.]`- wrong compared with the *solution* I got with [cho_solve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.cho_solve.html)

and *solve & solve_triangular* are used for the solution of `x=A^-1@b`

> **Anytime** you need to solve `x=A^-1*b` do not use unstable inverse - use `solve(A,b)`, that uses LAPACK